# The mongodb in Docker container is running ,but refuse to connect?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, docker

The error message is below

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
connecting to: test
2020-05-16T20:53:47.438+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2020-05-16T20:53:47.440+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6
```

By the way, is there any way to automatically seed the database in the Docker container?  I have to manually seed the data base every time.

Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

did you map the port of your localhost to MongoDB container? if not add -p 27017:27017 to your docker run command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to seed the database upon initialization, you can use the following as stated on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo):

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files with extensions .sh and .js that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.

You can do this by mounting a javascript or shell script file via `-v "./path/to/file.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/file.js"` or via the `volumes: ["./path/to/file.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/file.js"]` key of your mongodb service if you are using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).